# MVC3 File Input

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use the html file input to get the path and name of a file. I do not want to upload the file however, and seeing as the files can be quite large, I do not want to pass the file data back to the server either just to get the filename.

Is there a way to bind the file input value to a property in my model, or at least pass just the filename back to the server?

Here is my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Management", FormMethod.Post , new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})) {
    <div>
        Upload New Pricing Workbook: <input type="file" name="browse" id="browse" />
    </div>

    <div>Was Won: @Html.EditorFor(file => file.WasWon)</div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm ridiculously curious on this one - why in the world would you need just the local path to a file, and not the whole file?

Comment: I am using a service to parse the file and do not need it on the server, just the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to bind the file input value to a property in my model, or at least pass just the filename back to the server?

You will need javascript for this. You could include a hidden field to your form, and then subscribe for the submit handler of the form and inside this handler set the value of the hidden field from the value of the file input field and clear the value of the file field. Also if you are not interested in uploading the file you don't need the `enctype` attribute on the form

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#someHiddenField').val($('#browse').val());
    $('#browse').val(''); 
});
```

All this being said, for security reasons you cannot get the entire path to the file on the client computer using javascript. You will get only the filename using `$('#browse').val()` and that's the best you could hope.

If you want to get paths you could include a standard input field and let the user type it in. This way you will get on the server only what you need (a path to some file).

Comment: When you say hidden field, you mean hidden input, correct? Then you would need to make sure `Management/Upload` accepts an extra input (namely the file input value)

Comment: @Evan Layman, yes I mean hidden input field and yes the view model which the POST controller action should be adapted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I was just clarifying for my own sake and to possibly help shuniar

Comment: Thanks. This solution works for local files, but now I am having problems with mapped drives. This is in intranet application, but would it be better to upload the file for the parse then delete it when I am done? Or is there a way to get the UNC Path from the file input?

Comment: Have you ran a test, yet? If/when the user selects a file from the network drive, the UNC Path will be displayed in your input. You shouldn't have to do anything different (codewise) regardless of where the file came from.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to remove the `enctype` property of the form and the file name will be populated in your controller action as the `upload` string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty example that should be enough for you to update/tweak to fit your needs:

**The Model:**

```
public class HomeModel
{
   public string ClientFileName { get; set; }
}
```

**The Controller:**

```
   public class homeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            HomeModel hm = new HomeModel();
            if (Request.Form["selectedFilePath"] != null)
                hm.ClientFileName = Request.Form["selectedFilePath"];

            return View();
        }

    }
```

**The View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getFileName() {
        document.getElementById('selectedFilePath').value = document.getElementById('selectedFile').value;
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="/home/Index">
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" />
<input type="hidden" id="selectedFilePath" name="selectedFilePath" />
<button onclick="getFileName();">
    Submit file name</button>
</form>
```